# MySQL: I don't understand why this is happening?

Tags: python, mysql

```
import sqlite3
import traceback
from time import sleep
import mysql.connector


def check_user(user_id):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='online', user='root1', password='rootRRR111_')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS online(id INT, last_online_date TEXT)')
    conn.commit()
    select = "SELECT * FROM online WHERE id = %s LIMIT 0, 1"

    result = cur.execute(select, (user_id,))
    if result is None:
        insert = ('INSERT INTO online (id, last_online_date) VALUES (%s, %s)')
        cur.reset()
        cur.execute(insert, (user_id, online_time))
        conn.commit()

def update_online_status(user_id, online_time):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='online', user='root1', password='rootRRR111_')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    select = 'SELECT last_online_date FROM online WHERE id = %s'
    result = cursor.execute(select, (user_id,))
    old_online = result
    online_time = f'{old_online},{online_time}'
    cursor.reset()
    cursor.execute('UPDATE online SET last_online_date = %s WHERE id = %s', (online_time, user_id))
    conn.commit()


app = Client("my_account")
app.start()

while True:
    try:
        with open('ids.ini', 'r') as file:
            users = file.read().splitlines()

        for user in users:
            result = app.get_users(user)

            user_id = result['id']

            if result['status'] == 'offline':
                unix_timestamp = float(result['last_online_date'])
                local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
                local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp, local_timezone)

                online_time = local_time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

            elif result['status'] == 'online':
                now = datetime.now()
                online_time = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

            check_user(user_id)
            update_online_status(user_id, online_time)

        # sleep(300)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue


app.stop()
```

I am writing a program that would read the online status of a user in telegram.

Instead of writing online to an existing user, a huge number of identical rows appear in the database.

Example:
[Table with repetitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JncF.png)

When I try to fix something, there are a lot of errors.

> mysql.connector.errors.programmingerror: not all parameters were used in the sql statement
> mysql.connector.errors.internalerror: unread result found
> and other...

Pls help!!

Comment: In `check_user` use single `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of SELECT + INSERT. Of course, `online.id` must be defined as UNIQUE (maybe even as PRIMARY KEY).

Comment: Check the syntax - does `(user_id, online_time,)` must be used instead of `(user_id, online_time)`?

Comment: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: It turns out this error